# Triangle positioning using Javascript, CSS and HTML (other methods welcome)

Tags: javascript, html, css, combinations

I am trying to visualize a card game consisting of 20 triangles which can be placed in various ways. Each triangle has 3 sides, each of the sides has one counterpart in the remaining 19 triangles. Only if the sides match they can be put together.

[image]

the code that randomly generates possibilities is the following.( I am happy also for improvements on the code, which are, I am sure, plenty

### JAVSCRIPT

```
function Game() {
    this.cardsUnused = [];
    this.cardsUsed = [];
    this.possibleCards = [];
    this.insert = function (obj) {
        this.cardsUnused.push(obj);
    };
    this.useCard = function (obj) { // adds a triangle to the usedCards Array and removes it from the UnusedCards Array
        this.cardsUsed.push(obj);
        this.cardsUnused.remove(obj);
        this.possibleCards.remove(obj);// t (array.prototype.remove)
    };
    this.unuseCard = function (obj) { 
        this.cardsUnused.push(obj);
        this.cardsUsed.remove(obj);  
    };
}


// remove function
Array.prototype.remove = function () {
    var what, a = arguments, L = a.length, ax;
    while (L && this.length) {
        what = a[--L];
        while ((ax = this.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
            this.splice(ax, 1);
        }
    }
    return this;
};

var game = new Game();

// Triangle wird erstellt
function Triangle(name, sideA, sideB, sideC, Direction, position) {
    this.partName = name;
    this.sides = [sideA, sideB, sideC];
    this.sidesStatus = [0, 0, 0];
    this.sideDirection = Direction;
    this.stepUsed = 0;
    this.angle = 0;
    this.cardPosition = position;
    this.turn = function (winkel) {
        this.angle = this.angle + winkel;
    };
    this.useSide = function (side) {
        this.sidesStatus[side] = 1;
    };
}

var a = new Triangle("A", 1, 2, 21, 0, [0, 0]);
var b = new Triangle("B", 2, 3, 22, 0, [0, 0]);
var c = new Triangle("C", 3, 4, 23, 0, [0, 0]);
var d = new Triangle("D", 4, 5, 24, 0, [0, 0]);
var e = new Triangle("E", 5, 1, 25, 0, [0, 0]);
var f = new Triangle("F", 6, 21, 7, 180, [0, 0]);
var g = new Triangle("G", 7, 8, 26, 0, [0, 0]);
var h = new Triangle("H", 8, 22, 9, 180, [0, 0]);
var i = new Triangle("I", 9, 10, 27, 0, [0, 0]);
var j = new Triangle("J", 10, 23, 11, 180, [0, 0]);
var k = new Triangle("K", 11, 12, 28, 0, [0, 0]);
var l = new Triangle("L", 12, 24, 13, 180, [0, 0]);
var m = new Triangle("M", 13, 14, 29, 0, [0, 0]);
var n = new Triangle("N", 14, 25, 15, 180, [0, 0]);
var o = new Triangle("O", 15,  6, 30, 0, [0, 0]);
var p = new Triangle("P", 16, 26, 17, 180, [0, 0]);
var q = new Triangle("Q", 17, 27, 18, 180, [0, 0]);
var r = new Triangle("R", 18, 28, 19, 180, [0, 0]);
var s = new Triangle("S", 19, 29, 20, 180, [0, 0]);
var t = new Triangle("T", 20, 30, 16, 180, [0, 0]);

// an array with 20 triangles 
var triangles = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t];

// function to add triangles to the game
function addTriangles(arr) {
    var x;
    for (x = 0; x < arr.length; x += 1) {
        game.insert(triangles[x]);
    }
}

addTriangles(triangles);


game.useCard(a);



function toRadians (angle) {
  return angle * (Math.PI / 180);
}

function findRandomCardPossibleToUsedCards() {
    var isTrue = 0, randomIndexUsedCard, randomIndexUsedSide, randomIndexUnusedCard, randomIndexUnusedSide, position;
    while (isTrue === 0) {
        randomIndexUsedCard = Math.floor(Math.random() * game.cardsUsed.length);
        randomIndexUsedSide = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        randomIndexUnusedCard = Math.floor(Math.random() * game.cardsUnused.length);
        randomIndexUnusedSide = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        if (typeof game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard] === 'undefined') {
            document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "stopped";
        }
        // position = game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].cardPosition;

        if (game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].sidesStatus[randomIndexUsedSide] !== 1 && game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sidesStatus[randomIndexUnusedSide] !== 1) {
            if (game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].sides[randomIndexUsedSide] === game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sides[randomIndexUnusedSide]) {
                isTrue = 1;

                // the main problem I am having lies withing the next three " if -parts" and the translation into the css/html to depict the triangles in the correct way

                if (randomIndexUsedSide === 0) {

                    game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection = game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].sideDirection + 60;

                    game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].cardPosition[0] = game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].cardPosition[0] - 100 * Math.sin(toRadians(game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].sideDirection + 90));
                    game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].cardPosition[1] = game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].cardPosition[1] + 86 * Math.cos(toRadians(game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].sideDirection - 90));

                }
                if (randomIndexUsedSide === 1) {
                    game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection = game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].sideDirection - 60;

                    game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].cardPosition[0] = game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].cardPosition[0] - 100 * Math.sin(toRadians(game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].sideDirection -90));
                    game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].cardPosition[1] = game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].cardPosition[1] + 86 * Math.cos(toRadians(game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].sideDirection + 90));

                }
                if (randomIndexUsedSide === 2) {
                    game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection =  game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].sideDirection + 180;

                    game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].cardPosition[0] = game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].cardPosition[0] + 100 * Math.sin(toRadians(game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].sideDirection - 180));
                    game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].cardPosition[1] = game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].cardPosition[1] - 86 * Math.cos(toRadians(game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].sideDirection - 180));

                }


                game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].sidesStatus[randomIndexUsedSide] = 1;
                game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sidesStatus[randomIndexUnusedSide] = 1;

                var elem = document.getElementById(game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].partName);// STYLE

                var elemInner  = elem.getElementsByTagName('div');

                for (i = 0; i < elemInner.length; i++) {
                    elemInner = elemInner[i];
                }




                elem.className = elem.className + " used"; // STYLE

                //elemInner.style.transform = "rotate(" + game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection + "deg)" ;
                elem.style.transform = 
                "translate(" + game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].cardPosition[0] + 
                "px," + game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].cardPosition[1] + 
                "px)"  +" rotate(" + game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection + "deg)"  ;

                var elemA = document.getElementById(a.partName);// STYLE
                elemA.className = elemA.className + " used"; // STYLE

                game.useCard(game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard]);


            }
        }
    }

}
```

### CSS

```
 #game {
    width: 1000px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top: 300px;
}
.triangle {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;

    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.up {
    background-image: url(imgs/tri_up_red.png);

}



.down {
    background-image: url(imgs/tri_up_red.png);
}

.used {
    display: inline-block;
    visibility:visible;

}

.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.inner {
    width: 100px;
    height: 87px;
    margin-top: 6.5px;
    margin-bottom: 6.5px;

}
```

### HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="design.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body><div id="button">
        <button  onclick="findRandomCardPossibleToUsedCards()">add Triangle</button>
        </div>
        <div id="game" class="game">

        <div id="A" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner up"><span>A</span></div>

        </div>
        <div id="B" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner up"><span>B</span></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="C" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner up"><span>C</span></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="D" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner up"><span>D</span></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="E" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner up"><span>E</span></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="F" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner down"><span>F</span></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="G" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner up"><span>G</span></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="H" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner down"><span>H</span></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="I" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner up"><span>I</span></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="J" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner down"><span>J</span></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="K" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner up"><span>K</span></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="L" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner down"><span>L</span></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="M" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner up"><span>M</span></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="N" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner down"><span>N</span></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="O" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner up"><span>O</span></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="P" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner down"><span>P</span></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="Q" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner down"><span>Q</span></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="R" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner down"><span>R</span></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="S" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner down"><span>S</span></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="T" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner down"><span>T</span></div>

        </div>  

    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code to get the possible combinations works fine for me. As I said suggestions for improvement are welcome. My real problem is the visualization. In html all the divs are squares and and rotating and translating theses Squares/triangles gives me headaches. Correct rotations works and I think am on on the right path using the sine and cosine function to determine the translation in the x and y axis. But somehow I am stuck. I am not asking anyone to solve it for me but maybe someone can show me a different approach or point out where I was wrong.

Comment: another possibility: 
https://moa-office.at/cloud/public.php?service=files&t=fac1aff2a382c7d7e219450b4e486ab9

rotation is needed.picture in post is only on possibility. 

will have a look into css triangle. If they can have a background image, which is needed in my case.

-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535376/putting-an-image-background-onto-a-css-triangle

Answer (score 0):

I create a triangles for you with content inside:

I inspired by: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

**EDITED**

I create a triangle that you can move because the external div is a point in the center of the triangle. And could be easy for you calc the coordinates.

I create a new example:

http://codepen.io/luarmr/pen/GJmjZg

And this using the code http://codepen.io/luarmr/pen/MwmjqX you can click in the triangles.

HTML

```
<div class="card">
  <span class="value">test</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.card{
 height:0;
 width:0;
 position:absolute;
 top:50px;
 left:150px; 
 transition: all 2s;
}

.card:after{
  content:'';
  display:block;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
  position:absolute;
  left:-50px;
  top:-45px;
  z-index:1;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 90px solid #ebebeb;

  transition: all 2s;

}

.card.turn:after{  
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.card.turn{  
  left:200px;
}

.card .value{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
  top:-10px;
  width:90px;
  left:-45px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: I did this in angular, only for show you my way to use this css: http://codepen.io/luarmr/pen/MwmjqX
You only need apply transform to the ul to put the numbers in the correct  position with a 3 different class for example.

Comment: btw look interesting the game :)

Comment: thanks so far..will have a closer look into it tomorrow. Need to enjoy the weather....when it's finished I will let you have a look.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution that works for me:

the positioning of the hard to position triangles I have solved by having different square picture of turned triangles instead of turning the triangles and getting hard to work with x and y coordinates and centers of the divs. from there on it was a piece of cake.

### JAVASCRIPT

```
function Game() {
    this.cardsUnused = [];
    this.cardsUsed = [];
    this.insert = function (obj) {
        this.cardsUnused.push(obj);
    };
    this.useCard = function (obj) { // fügt ein Triangle dem Benutzen Stapel hinzu und entfernt sie vom unbenutzen Stapel
        this.cardsUsed.push(obj);
        this.cardsUnused.remove(obj);
    };
    this.unuseCard = function (obj) { // fügt ein Triangle dem unbenutzebn Stapel hinzu und entfernt sie vom benutzen Stapel
        this.cardsUnused.push(obj);
        this.cardsUsed.remove(obj);  // remove Funktion weiter unten definiert (array.prototype.remove)
    };
}



Array.prototype.remove = function () {
    var what, a = arguments, L = a.length, ax;
    while (L && this.length) {
        what = a[--L];
        while ((ax = this.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
            this.splice(ax, 1);
        }
    }
    return this;
};


var game = new Game();

// Triangle wird erstellt
function Triangle(name, sideA, sideB, sideC, directionSide, position) {
    this.partName = name;
    this.sides = [sideA, sideB, sideC];
    this.sidesStatus = [0, 0, 0];
    this.sideDirection = directionSide;
    this.stepUsed = 0;
    this.angle = 0;
    this.cardPosition = position;
    this.useSide = function (side) {
        this.sidesStatus[side] = 1;
    };
}
    // creating 20 triangles
var a = new Triangle("A", 1, 21, 2, [60, 180, 300], [0, 0]);
var b = new Triangle("B", 2, 22, 3, [0, 0, 0], [0, 0]);
var c = new Triangle("C", 3, 23, 4, [0, 0, 0], [0, 0]);
var d = new Triangle("D", 4, 24, 5, [0, 0, 0], [0, 0]);
var e = new Triangle("E", 5, 25, 1, [0, 0, 0], [0, 0]);
var f = new Triangle("F", 6, 7, 21, [0, 0, 0], [0, 0]);
var g = new Triangle("G", 7, 26, 8, [0, 0, 0], [0, 0]);
var h = new Triangle("H", 8, 9, 22, [0, 0, 0], [0, 0]);
var i = new Triangle("I", 9, 27, 10, [0, 0, 0], [0, 0]);
var j = new Triangle("J", 10, 11, 23, [0, 0, 0], [0, 0]);
var k = new Triangle("K", 11, 28, 12, [0, 0, 0], [0, 0]);
var l = new Triangle("L", 12, 13, 24, [0, 0, 0], [0, 0]);
var m = new Triangle("M", 13, 29, 14, [0, 0, 0], [0, 0]);
var n = new Triangle("N", 14, 15, 25, [0, 0, 0], [0, 0]);
var o = new Triangle("O", 15,  30, 6, [0, 0, 0], [0, 0]);
var p = new Triangle("P", 16, 17, 26, [0, 0, 0], [0, 0]);
var q = new Triangle("Q", 17, 18, 27, [0, 0, 0], [0, 0]);
var r = new Triangle("R", 18, 19, 28, [0, 0, 0], [0, 0]);
var s = new Triangle("S", 19, 20, 29, [0, 0, 0], [0, 0]);
var t = new Triangle("T", 20, 16, 30, [0, 0, 0], [0, 0]);

    // creates an array with all triangles
var triangles = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t];

    // function to add triangles to game
function addTriangles(arr) {
    var x;
    for (x = 0; x < arr.length; x += 1) {
        game.insert(triangles[x]);
    }
}
    // adding the triangles
addTriangles(triangles);

    ///// Game built up

var v = 0;

var randomIndexUsedCard, randomIndexUsedSide, randomIndexUnusedCard, randomIndexUnusedSide;
    // Helper function
function toRadians(angle) {
    return angle * (Math.PI / 180);
}

game.useCard(a); // lay down first triangle



    // main function that runs on click on button / max  19 times 
function findRandomCardPossibleToUsedCards2() {
    for (v = 0; v < 19; v = v + 1) {


        var isTrue = 0;
        while (isTrue === 0) { // runs as long as no random possible card is found
            randomIndexUsedCard = Math.floor(Math.random() * game.cardsUsed.length); // chooses a random triangle from triangles already used ( first time only a) 
            randomIndexUsedSide = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); // chooses a random side of the randomly chosen triangle
            randomIndexUnusedCard = Math.floor(Math.random() * game.cardsUnused.length); // chooses a random triangle from the unused triangles
            randomIndexUnusedSide = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); // and also a random side from the chosen unused triangle
            if (typeof game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard] === 'undefined') { // hides button to choose triangle when all cards have been used
                document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "fertig";
            }

            if (game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].sidesStatus[randomIndexUsedSide] !== 1 && game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sidesStatus[randomIndexUnusedSide] !== 1) {
                if (game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].sides[randomIndexUsedSide] === game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sides[randomIndexUnusedSide]) {
                    isTrue = 1;

                    for ( var x = 0; x < 3; x = x +1) {
                    if (randomIndexUsedSide === x) {

                        if (game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].sideDirection[x] === 0) {
                            game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].cardPosition[0] = game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].cardPosition[0];
                            game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].cardPosition[1] = game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].cardPosition[1] - 87;
                        }
                        if (game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].sideDirection[x] === 60) {
                            game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].cardPosition[0] = game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].cardPosition[0] - 50;
                            game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].cardPosition[1] = game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].cardPosition[1];
                        }
                        if (game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].sideDirection[x] === 120) {
                            game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].cardPosition[0] = game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].cardPosition[0] - 50;
                            game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].cardPosition[1] = game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].cardPosition[1];
                        }
                        if (game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].sideDirection[x] === 180) {
                            game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].cardPosition[0] = game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].cardPosition[0];
                            game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].cardPosition[1] = game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].cardPosition[1] + 87;
                        }
                        if (game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].sideDirection[x] === 240) {
                            game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].cardPosition[0] = game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].cardPosition[0] + 50;
                            game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].cardPosition[1] = game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].cardPosition[1];
                        }
                        if (game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].sideDirection[x] === 300) {
                            game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].cardPosition[0] = game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].cardPosition[0] + 50;
                            game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].cardPosition[1] = game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].cardPosition[1];
                        }
                        if (game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].sideDirection[x] === 360) {
                            game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].cardPosition[0] = game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].cardPosition[0];
                            game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].cardPosition[1] = game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].cardPosition[1] - 87;
                        }
                    }
                    }



                    for (u = 0; u < game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection.length; u = u + 1) {
                        if (game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[u] >= 360) {
                            game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[u] = game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[u] - 360;
                        }
                        if (game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[u] < 0) {
                            game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[u] = game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[u] + 360;
                        }
                    }

                    game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[randomIndexUnusedSide] = game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].sideDirection[randomIndexUsedSide] + 180;

                    if (game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[0] === game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[randomIndexUnusedSide]) {
                        game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[1] = game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[0] + 120;
                        game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[2] = game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[0] - 120;
                    }

                    if (game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[1] === game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[randomIndexUnusedSide]) {
                        game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[2] = game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[1] + 120;
                        game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[0] = game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[1] - 120;
                    }
                    if (game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[2] === game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[randomIndexUnusedSide]) {
                        game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[0] = game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[2] + 120;
                        game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[1] = game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[2] - 120;
                    }

                    for (w = 0; w < 3; w = w + 1) {
                        if (game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[w] >= 360) {
                            game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[w] = game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[w] - 360;
                        }
                        if (game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[w] < 0) {
                            game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[w] = game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[w] + 360;
                        }
                    }

                    game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].sidesStatus[randomIndexUsedSide] = 1;
                    game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sidesStatus[randomIndexUnusedSide] = 1;


                    // STYLE STYLE 
                    var elem = document.getElementById(game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].partName);
                    var elemUsed = document.getElementById(game.cardsUsed[randomIndexUsedCard].partName);
                    var elemInner  = elem.getElementsByTagName('div');

                    for (y = 0; y < elemInner.length; y = y + 1) {
                        elemInner = elemInner[y];
                    }



                    elem.className = elem.className + " used"; // STYLE

                    elemInner.style.backgroundImage = "url(imgs/tri" + game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].partName + (game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection[0]) + ".png)";
                    console.log(game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].partName + (game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection));
                    // elemInner.style.transform = "rotate(" + game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection + "deg)" ;
                    elem.style.transform =
                        "translate(" + Math.floor(game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].cardPosition[0]) +
                        "px," + Math.floor(game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].cardPosition[1]) +
                        "px)"; // + " rotate(" + game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard].sideDirection + "deg)"   ;

                    var elemA = document.getElementById(a.partName);
                    elemA.className = elemA.className + " used"; 


                    game.useCard(game.cardsUnused[randomIndexUnusedCard]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="design.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body><div id="button">
        <button  onclick="findRandomCardPossibleToUsedCards2()">add Triangle</button>
        </div>
        <div id="game" class="game">

        <div id="A" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner up"></div>

        </div>
        <div id="B" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner up"></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="C" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner up"></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="D" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner up"></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="E" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner up"></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="F" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner down"></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="G" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner up"></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="H" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner down"></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="I" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner up"></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="J" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner down"></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="K" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner up"></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="L" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner down"></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="M" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner up"></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="N" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner down"></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="O" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner up"></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="P" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner down"></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="Q" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner down"></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="R" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner down"></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="S" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner down"></div>

        </div>  
        <div id="T" class="triangle">
            <div class="inner down"></div>

        </div>  

    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

### CSS

```
#game {
    postion: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top: 300px;
}
.triangle {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100px;
    height:87px;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
}


.used {
    display: inline-block;
    visibility:visible;

}

.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}



.inner {
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 100px !important;
    height:87px !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-origin:padding-box;
    background-position: top;
    margin: auto;
    background-size: contain;
    transform-origin: center;
    opacity: 0,7;
    /*border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 86px solid #ebebeb; */
}

#A .inner {
    background-image: url(imgs/triA.png);
```